# Is there a tool to convert .actionScriptProperties to flex-config.xml?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, mxmlc

I'm looking for a tool that could convert Flex settings set inside Flash Builder, stored in `.actionScriptProperties` and `.flexProperties`, to a `flex-config.xml`-like file that could be used as an input to Flex compilers and tools (`mxmlc`, `compc` and `asdoc`). Is there such a thing?

Comment: Nothing that I know of.  Speaking from a stance of ignorance, I thought that .actionScriptProperties and .flexProperties were eclipse specific settings and unrelated to the Flex compiler.  The Flex SDK comes with a default config file which is used by Flash Builder when compiling the app.

Comment: Whatever you set in project properties > *Flex Compiler* page will be stored in `.actionScriptProperties`. But it certainly is Eclipse (Flash Builder) specific.

Answer (score 3):

If there's no conversion tool then the best bet is probably adding `-dump-config=c:\xyz.xml` to the compiler options in Flash Builder.